# Why do i get this error when i'm trying to install shadcn ui

Tags: reactjs, forms, vite, npm-install, shadcnui

I am creating a small project with vite and i keep getting this error when i try to run `npx shadcn-ui@latest init`

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I appreciate any help as I'm relatively new to react and debugging is still an issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new folder "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm" and do `npx shadcn-ui@latest init` command again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you when I created the app inside a git repository.
So what I did was to run the command `npx create-next-app@latest my-app --typescript --tailwind --eslint` in cmd and after that u go to the repository where your app has been created and launch the command `npx shadcn-ui@latest init` in there and it work well !

Answer (score 0):

just go to this path :  ---->C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming <---- and create a folder called "npm" .
that solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Created a folder "npm" in `"C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Roaming"` and then redo the command again This allows the package to be seen in files it runs thru

Hope that helps!